# Is it possible to manually TRIM the unused blocks (free space) for an existing APFS volume?

Tags: ssd, apfs, trim

When migrating a MacBook from HDD to SSD, I did a block-level copy using `dd`. I believe for optimal flash lifetime and performance, it would be the best to issue a TRIM for every unused block in the new filesystem to inform the SSD controller (so it won't confuse my `dd` copy with a large file that occupies the entire disk).

Is it possible to TRIM the free space manually for an APFS volume on macOS (like FreeBSD's `trim` or Linux's `fstrim`)?  I've read that on HFS+, macOS's `fsck` has a TRIM pass, so TRIM can be triggered manually by running `fsck -fy` in single-user mode, and one should see a "trimming unused blocks" message. But it doesn't support APFS (I tried it and I didn't see any message about TRIM).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On APFS, macOS automatically performs a TRIM operation on the free disk space on boot via the AFPS Space Manager (spaceman). Therefore, as long as TRIM is enabled on the system (via `trimforce` for 3rd-party SSDs, see karolus's answer), you don't have to worry about it. There is no command and no need to manually trim the unused blocks.

#### Verification

If you want to personally verify the operation of boot time TRIM, you can search for spaceman-related messages in your boot log.

Execute the following command as root. It lists all messages from the kernel (`--predicate "processID == 0"`) since the beginning of this month (`--start $(date "+%Y-%m-01"`) and search for messages that contain "spaceman" (`grep spaceman`).

```
# log show --predicate "processID == 0" \
  --start $(date "+%Y-%m-01") | grep spaceman
```

And you can see messages like these

```
2021-01-13 11:54:28.559149+0800 0x1bc      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) spaceman_trim_free_blocks:3009: scan took 7.102084 s, trims took 6.415750 s
2021-01-13 11:54:28.565684+0800 0x1bc      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) spaceman_trim_free_blocks:3017: 28059445 blocks free in 247937 extents
2021-01-13 11:54:28.572872+0800 0x1bc      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) spaceman_trim_free_blocks:3025: 28059445 blocks trimmed in 247937 extents (25 us/trim, 38645 trims/s)
2021-01-13 11:54:28.580121+0800 0x1bc      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) spaceman_trim_free_blocks:3028: trim distribution 1:25496 2+:47953 4+:92857 16+:41261 64+:17838 256+:22532
```

The lines are too long to read, I slightly edited it to make it shorter. You should see logs lines that mentions "TRIM",

```
scan took 7.102084 s, trims took 6.415750 s
28059445 blocks free in 247937 extents
28059445 blocks trimmed in 247937 extents (25 us/trim, 38645 trims/s)
trim distribution 1:25496 2+:47953 4+:92857 16+:41261 64+:17838 256+:22532
```

As you can see, macOS just trimmed 28059445 unused blocks today. Assuming APFS uses a 4 KiB block size, it means the SSD has discarded 107 GiB of free space. And yes, it roughly matches the free space on my disk. Works as expected!

Answer (score 2):

Per [cnet](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/installing-ssd-on-mac-trim-mistake/), you should be able to check if TRIM is running (article has video) under System Information > SATA. If it isn't available, per the article, run:

`sudo trimforce enable`

Approving it will require a restart, but you should be able to verify it's now enabled back under System Information.

Additionally, APFS-formatted volumes will automatically run TRIM on boot, so no commands will be listed to manually do this.

Comment: Yes, but this only enables TRIM for future file operations. I don't think enabling TRIM will cause an immediate discard of existing free blocks (which is what I want). If I don't fill my disk with a large file and delete it, I think the existing free space will never be trimmed...

Comment: So, would it be something you would have to enable before copying over?

Comment: After some research, I discovered APFS will automatically TRIM your free space on boot, which explains why there is no tool for that. So yeah, just reboot and it should work (I confirmed it in the kernel log)!

Comment: That's great!  I can edit the answer to reflect this.